# How to find text on the screen and determine the location?

Tags: java, text

I have text in the screen. I want my program to find the text on the screen, and tell me the absolute coordinates on the screen. The text on the screen is not part of my java program.

How might one do this?

Comment: That's pretty much impossible. Please edit the question to describe exactly what you are trying to do. There might be another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Robot.createScreenCapture()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture%28java.awt.Rectangle%29) to take a screenshot.

But to actually read and find the text you need some OCR software or implement your own implementation in Java. You don't know how the text is displayed, which font, which size, which color, ClearType .... That's the tricky part.